# Is changing the src attribute considered Ajax?

Tags: ajax

Is changing the src attribute of a image, so another image is loaded considered Ajax? Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I am having a hard time understanding what ajax really is.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's just regular JS. Ajax is the *specific* technique of sending and receiving data from the server using the `XMLHttpRequest` object.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax involves a web page doing the following:

- Making a HTTP request using Javascript.
- Reading and parsing the response from that request, using Javascript.

In addition, if you want to be pedantic about it, the "X" in Ajax technically refers to "XML": originally, it was expected that both the request and response would be sent and received as XML code, due to it being easy to encode and parse in Javascript, using the DOM. However these days that technicality is largely ignored, as most people now use JSON for this instead. The term "Ajax" has remained in use, though.